# Flutter : Is it bad practice for a ChangeNotifier subclass to hold a ScrollController?

Tags: flutter, architecture

I think it's very normal to use StatefulWidget to implement the following in an app that controls ListView scrolling.

```
//sample(a)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Go to ListViewPage'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        ChangeNotifierProvider<ListViewPageController>(
                      create: (_) => ListViewPageController(),
                      child: ListViewPage(),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListViewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListViewPage> createState() => _ListViewPageState();
}

class _ListViewPageState extends State<ListViewPage> {
  final ScrollController sc = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          controller: sc,
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text('$index'));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

---

On the other hand, I think that the following implementation that manages ListViewPage scrolling using ChangeNotifier/Provider (Not Riverpod) without using StatefulWidget can also be considered. The actual execution itself is done without problems.

```
////sample(b)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ListViewPageController extends ChangeNotifier {
  ScrollController sc = ScrollController();
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Go to ListViewPage'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        ChangeNotifierProvider<ListViewPageController>(
                          create: (_) => ListViewPageController(),
                          child: ListViewPage(),
                        ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListViewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //↓Is this part mandatory?
  /*
  late final ScrollController sc = context.read<ListViewPageController>().sc;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          controller: context.read<ListViewPageController>().sc,
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text('$index'));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**Question1**
Sample(b) has the same behavior as sample(a), but since ListViewPage is StatelessWidget, sc.dispose is not called.

My current understanding is that the ListViewPageController will be destroyed when we back from ListViewPage to HomePage, but will the ScrollController be also automatically destroyed at that point?
Shouldn't I write the code about sc.dispose myself?

Or do I have to make the ListViewPage a StatefulWidget and write the code myself to call sc.dispose in state.dispose?

---

**Question2**
Recently, I heard the following claim (explanation).

"Subclasses of ChangeNotifier (or StateNotfier) should not depend on any UI code.
Flutter's ScrollController/PageController/TextEditingController/Forms, etc. are classes in the Flutter SDK (that is, UI code).
So in this example the ListViewPageController should not have(depend on) a ScrollController. ”

Is this correct?

I also saw another sample code that uses Scrollable.ensureVisible to control scrolling, but since this Scrollable class is also UI code, is it a bad practice to use it in a ChangeNotifier subclass as shown below?
(In this case each ListTile should have a GlobalKey.)

Personally, I think it would be easier to understand if the ChangeNotifier subclass held the ScrollController,PageController, etc.
How important is this theory when developing in Flutter?

```
class ListViewPageController extends ChangeNotifier {
  ScrollController sc = ScrollController();
  
  scrollRequest(int scrollIndex) {
    Scrollable.ensureVisible(keyList[scrollIndex - 100].currentContext!,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
        alignment: 0.5,
        alignmentPolicy: ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.explicit);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1. In sample b, sc is an obj< ScrollController > in another obj< ListViewPageController >, let's say it's lc.

When lc is (disposed)->deleted, surely will sc be (disposed)->deleted.

Q2. Holding ScrollController in ListViewPageController may cause error when you accidentally dispose ListViewPageController while ListViewPage was still alive.

If you want to access ScrollController, try inject it into ListViewPageController would be a better practice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean.
Do you mean "when the ListViewPageController is deleted the ScrollController is automatically deleted"?

Comment: @森口万太郎 I've edited my answer. Yes I mean when ListViewPageController is deleted the ScrollController is automatically deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If you don't mind, could you point me to an explanation for it in the official docs or something similar?

Comment: @森口万太郎 check this link below discussed about the GC in dart. https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-dont-fear-the-garbage-collector-d69b3ff1ca30

Comment: Normally we don't worry about the memory release problem in dart. The ScrollController is instantiated in ListViewPageController when ListViewPageController is instantiated in a StatelessWidget in sample B.
HomePage is a StatelessWidget, so sure it don't have dispose method.
When the StatelessWidget is deleted it becomes unreachable. The ScrollController which instantiated in this StatelessWidget will also become unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

You can call dispose method inside ListViewPageController  too and dispose ScrollController sc there, and i too use this approach but i am not sure if its the right approach.

```
class ListViewPageController extends ChangeNotifier {
 ScrollController sc = ScrollController();
 @override
void dispose(){
 sc.dispose();
}
}
```